# Reading node field values in module code using Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, cck

I have created a custom module and am using hook_block to programmatically create some blocks.

My question is how can I access field values including CCK fields for the current node within my module?

I basically want to get a value from a CCK field and use the value when building my block for that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting at the current node is an awkward pain in the posterior. Standard practice is to do something like this:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == '') {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  // Collect output.
}
```

`arg()` pulls elements out of the Drupal path. Since all nodes (regardless of what a path alias might show you) appears at node/#, by checking for 'node' and that the second element is a number, you are fairly well guaranteed to have your hands on a node. Checking the third path element allows you to avoid processing on the node edit form and other pages that hang off a specific node.

CCK Values are loaded into the node, and usually look something like this:

```
// Text field. Structure also works for number fields.
$text = $node->field_my_text_field[0]['value']
// Node Reference field.
$nref = $node->field_my_nref_field[0]['nid']
// User Reference field.
$uref = $node->field_my_uref_field[0]['uid']
```

The "0" array element specifies the *delta* of the field. Any given field can actually process multiple values, and the array structure in CCK assumes this possibility even if you restrict the field to a single value.

Comment: That's fantastic thanks. I'm surprised there is not an built-in Drupal function to get the node id!

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6 there is a built-in Drupal function to get the node object.

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  …
}
```

Read more here http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_get_item/6.